# CodeIgniter - multiple results with foreach?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I was trying to do simple news system with CodeIgniter, and I've done that. But I've problem with displaying the results. Actually, they're displaying right as I wanted to, but I can not display more than one of them.

I'm using 'foreach' for that, and the thing is, that, when I'm putting my style inside foreach, and displaying it in it, then it works well. But when I'm trying to define these datas first, and then display them (outside the foreach), then only one record is showing up.

What I wanted to do, and **doesn't work**:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $row) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $text = $row['text'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $autor_id = $row['user_id'];
}

echo $title; ?>
```

What works, but isn't comfortable to use for me:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $p): ?>
    <h2><?php echo htmlspecialchars($p['title']); ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($p['text'])); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Is it even possible to do this that way that I'm trying to do?

Comment: Read more about what iteration is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just combine the two:

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $row) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $text = $row['text'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $autor_id = $row['user_id'];?>
    <h2><?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($text)); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Or use `echo` inside the loop and you don't need to break the PHP tags.